# How to get the total count in observableArray

Tags: knockout-2.0

I have this list of datas:

```
var data = [
{"AMSnack": true, "PMSnack": false},
{"AMSnack": true, "PMSnack": false},
{"AMSnack": true, "PMSnack": false},
{"AMSnack": fale, "PMSnack": true},
{"AMSnack": true, "PMSnack": false}];
```

I want to get the total of AMSnack that is true and the PMSnack that is also true.
How can I get the totals inside of the observableArray?

here's the full code http://jsfiddle.net/comfreakph/gtPGz/5/

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to see as the result in your sample? 5 because there is 5 true, 0 because there is no item where AMSnack AND PMSnack also true? Or 4 for AMSnack and 1 for PMSnack?

Comment: I want to get the total count of the true and the false. but it seems you already posted the answer i want. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your `GetCount` as `ko.computed` (see [doc](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)) where you can use the `ko.utils.arrayFilter` (see [doc](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html)) function to filter your array.

To get the count you just need to return the `length` of the filtered array:

```
self.GetCount = ko.computed(function(){
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.Data(), function(item) {
        //return item.AMSnack || item.PMSnack; // AMSnack or PMSnack true
         return item.AMSnack && item.PMSnack; // AMSnack and PMSnack true
        }).length;
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/RFRQC/)